# Swift View Controller and Navigation Controller

Tags: swift

When adding a ViewController should you always add a Navigation Controller?  What is the benefits for using a navigation controller?

I know the navigation controller will give you a a back button but that can be accomplished using Navigation Bar and add your own back button.

Now going from screen to screen doesnt seem that much more complicated:

To seque to another view code:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginViewSegue", sender: self)
```

To navigate to another view:

```
let loginController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginView") as! LoginViewController

self.presentViewController(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I know to the seque code is just a one liner while the other one is two liners.  But that doesnt seem like a big deal.  I know on seque you get helper classes also that you can use.  Like prepareForSegue that is executed before the seque actually gets called.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
```

but calling the view controller alows you this to by just running pre-code before calling the view.

It this just a matter of style or is there a benefit of one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It this just a matter of style

You seem to be asking about two different things: navigation controller vs. presented view controller on the one hand, and code vs. storyboard on the other.

#### Navigation controller vs. presented controller

It's a matter of the relationship between the view controllers and the behavior of the views.

- A navigation controller (push and pop) is about having a single *stack* of view controllers. The navigation controller provides its own view with a nav bar and a toolbar, and you get the whole population of the nav bar automatically along with the back button. Your view controller is the navigation controller's child, and your view controller's view is inside that interface.
- A presented view controller (present and dismiss) is about replacing the view controller that presents it. The view controllers stand in the relationship of presenting and presented view controller (not a parent-child relationship). The view of the latter covers (partially or totally) or replaces the view of the former.

And those aren't the only options. Tab bar controllers and page view controllers are other built-in parent view controller possibilities. And you can write your own custom parent view controller. Use what makes sense for your app's architecture. Apple is just trying to provide a kind of standard vocabulary that helps you write apps easily and helps the user understand where we are and where are going (and where we came from) as views come and go.

#### Code vs. storyboard

Anything you can do in the storyboard you can do in pure code. It's entirely up to you.

Comment: Can I use one Navigation controller for different Views?

Comment: I don't know what that question means. You can push as many view controllers onto the stack as you like. It's a stack. - Reading my book might help you: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html